# Submersion, diffeomorphism, and embedding

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $\pi:M \rightarrow N$ a submersion and $f:S \rightarrow M$ a smooth map such that $\pi \circ f : S \rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism. Show that  $f:S \rightarrow M $ is an embedding.

I'm having trouble showing that $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image with the subspace topology. I already showed that $f$ is an immersion and I tried to show that is an open map using the fact that submersions are open but got stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f' : S \stackrel{f}{\to} f(S)$ and $i : f(S) \hookrightarrow M$. These are continuous maps such that $i \circ f' = f$. By definition $f'$ is a surjection.

We know that $\pi \circ f$ is a diffeomorphism, in particular a homeomorphism.
The map $p = (\pi \circ f)^{-1} \circ  \pi \circ i : f(S) \to S$ is continuous. We have $p \circ f' = id_S$ which shows that $f'$ is an injection (if $f'(x) = f'(y)$, then $x = p(f'(x)) =  p(f'(y)) = y$). Thus $f'$ is a bijection with inverse $(f')^{-1} : f(S) \to S$. But we have $(f')^{-1} = id_S \circ (f')^{-1} = p \circ f \circ (f')^{-1} = p$ which shows that $(f')^{-1}$ is continuous, Thus $f'$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I'm surprised that I never used that $\pi$ is a submersion neither for proving that f is an immersion nor embedding, maybe that hypotesis is not neccesary. I only used that $\pi \circ f$ is an diffeomorphism and then used that its differential will be an isomorphism.

Comment: @TomásSentagne Indeed we do not need to assume that $\pi$ is a submersion. Since $\pi \circ f$ is a diffeomorphism, $f$ must be an immersion.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{s_i\}$ is a sequence in $S$ such that $f(s_i)\to f(s)$, for some $s$ in $S$, then
$\pi(f(s_i))\to \pi(f(s))$, so $s_i\to s$, because $\pi\circ f$ is a homeomorphism.  This shows that $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: How does this use that $\pi$ is a submersion?

Comment: It doesn't.  (Extra stuff to get the min n.o of chars in a comment)